# How to generate monthly uptime report of GCP compute engine vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring, monitoring-query-language

I am trying to generate **MONTHLY** report for total uptime of a single GCP compute vm instance inclusive of restarts.

```
Eg: In the past 24 hours if instance is not running for 1hr , i expect the mql query to return 23 hrs
```

MQL query used:

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric 'compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime'
| filter (metric.instance_name == 'instance-1')
| align delta(30d)
| every 30d
| group_by [], [value_uptime_mean: mean(value.uptime)]
```

This query is not providing the exact timings my servers are up/down.
If you have any idea on how to get information of total uptime through **MQL** that would be very helpful.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the metric description in [Google Cloud metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp?hl=en), I think you should use `compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime_total` for the calculation.

```
fetch gce_instance
| metric compute.googleapis.com/instance/uptime_total
| filter (metric.instance_name == 'instance-1')
| group_by [], sliding(30d), [uptime_total_sum: sum(value.uptime_total)]
```